# Failed to build app using libboost_thread

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, g++

I followed [get started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) to build and install `boost 1.61.0` to `mypath-to-boost`, then tried to use `libboost_thread` below,

```
// mythread.cpp

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void a_thread() {}

int main() {
  boost::thread t{a_thread};
}
```

building `mythread.cpp`,

```
$ g++ mythread.cpp -std=c++11 -Imypath-to-boost -lboost_thread -Lmypath-to-boost/lib
```

then got errors,

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.61.0, needed by mypath-to-boost/lib/libboost_thread.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
mythread.cpp: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
...
```

checking `libboost_thread`,

```
$ ls -l mypath-to-boost/lib/*thread*
```

then found the libs,

```
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.61.0
libboost_thread.so.1.61.0
```

So what's the problem to cause the build failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `boost_system` library to link line...

Comment: A side question: the source above can't be compiled if the function `a_thread` is put behind `main`. `gcc` complains too much, why?